# How to retrieve a WhatsApp message in Twilio?

Tags: python, twilio

I am able to send messages to my WhatsApp number through Twilio in python, however I want to be able to retrieve received messages as well. Anyone know a function or something?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can retrieve WhatsApp messages sent to your Twilio number using the [message resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#read-multiple-message-resources). For example, retrieving the messages sent to your WhatsApp number in Python looks like this:

```py
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

messages = client.messages.list(limit=20, to=YOUR_WHATSAPP_NUMBER)

for record in messages:
    print(record.sid)
```

Comment: That helps, how can I convert that into text though as my current output from that is the account Sid and Sid.

Comment: Try `record.body`. All of the properties are listed in the documentation linked in my answer.